# Do user-generated content and votes count as personal data under the General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR)?

Tags: privacy, gdpr, european-union

Do user-generated content and votes count as personal data under the  [General Data Protection Regulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation) (GDPR)?

For example, on Stack Exchange, do the questions, answers, comments, messages and votes count as personal data?

Answer (score 1):

### Yes

Posts on social networks are explicitly called out as personal data.

Comment: Thank you. Is Stack Exchange a social network, and where did you read that  social networks are explicitly called out as personal data?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt yes and in the link you provided respectively

Comment: Good catch, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Under GDPR Personal Data is any Data that either on its own (e.g. a photograph) or when cross-referenced with other Data enables to univocally identify one given natural person.

If user generated content allows the identification and/ or Profiling of that natural person then... Yes.

At least for the platform such "link" between the person and the information/ Data is direct... so YES.